# Como faço para chamar o metodo intercepta() de uma classe de Intercept, em outro método do projeto?

Tags: java, java-ee, vraptor

Tudo bem pessoal?

Bom, estou com uma dificuldade e gostaria de uma ajudinha.

Eu tenho o seguinte método da minha classe AcessarIntercept:

```
@Intercepts
@RequestScoped
public class AcessarIntercept {
    @AroundCall
    public void intercepta(SimpleInterceptorStack stack) {
        // Conteúdo do método que redireciona a página
        // após fazer as verificações de interceptação.
    }

}
```

E eu gostaria de invocar esse método no meu Controller ou outra classe. 
Como faço isso?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, não seria apenas intanciar a classe em um objeto e chamar o intercepta, seria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Correção*

Você poderia passar como parâmetro do seu construtor a instanciação da classe que você quer executar:

```
public class Controller {
     private AcessarIntercept acessar;

     public Controller(AcessarIntercept acessar) {
         this.acessar = acessar; 
     }
}
```

E assim executar seu método com `acessar.intercept()`. Apenas lembre de alocar memória em seu objeto "acessar" antes de criar seu Controller.

Comment: Só não entendi a parte do "*Apenas lembre de alocar memória antes de criar seu Controller.*", uma vez que o Java tem gerenciamento automático de memória e não há nada que o programador precise fazer para isso.

Comment: Java gerencia o desalocamento de memória por meio do Garbage Collector, a parte de alocação é realizada pelo programador ao utilizar o operador new. Basicamente disse para não esquecer de alocar o objeto "acessar" que você passa como parâmetro do construtor.

Comment: Ou seja, o que você quis dizer é que não é para passar `null` no construtor. Um `Objects.requireNonNull(acessar);` ou um `if (acessar == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();` no começo do construtor resolveria isso.